# Why if...else stop working after I switched to DBO?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, pdo

I have this code now.

```
$select_links = "SELECT * FROM $table";
if (isset($_POST['link'])) {
    if ($_POST['link'] == '0'){
    }}
else {

$links = $conn->prepare($select_links);
$links->execute();
$links->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
while($row1 = $links->fetch())
{
echo $row1['name'];
};
}
```

When I load page without _POST, `echo $row1['name'];` works. But if I send POST `link=1` it dont works. Why? I need to make it not work only if POST contains `link=0`.

P.S. It works before I switced to DBO.

Comment: How does "not work" look like exactly?

Comment: Nothing happens. Like `echo $row...` dont exist. If I remove if-else part, `echo $row...` works.

Comment: PHP is probably throwing an error but it's not being shown. I suggest turning on PHP's error reporting, so that you actually get to see the error message. That might help you work out what the problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not whatever "DBO" but the code you wrote.
Although I managed to get it's meaning only after reformatting it sanely. 
Here it goes:

```
$select_links = "SELECT * FROM $table";
if (isset($_POST['link'])) {
    if ($_POST['link'] == '0'){
        // do nothing
    }
} else {
    $links = $conn->prepare($select_links);
    $links->execute();
    $links->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    while($row1 = $links->fetch())
    {
        echo $row1['name'];
    }
}
```

So, when you set POST link=1, it is passed `isset($_POST['link'])` check and then no other code being executed.

Most likely you meant something like this

```
if (!empty($_POST['link'])) {
    $select_links = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $links = $conn->prepare($select_links);
    $links->execute();
    $links->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    while($row1 = $links->fetch())
    {
        echo $row1['name'];
    }
}
```

If you need some other logic - no problem, code whatever behaviour you want.
Just read the manual and test everything you try.
...but okay, this one could be hard for a newcomer:

```
if (!isset($_POST['link']) || $_POST['link']) {
```

means

```
IF $_POST['link'] is NOT set OR $_POST['link'] NOT equal to 0
```